# URl pattern Matching in php without http or www

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a html file that has some link like

```
<a href="clash/football/a-vs-b">

<a href="clash/football/dsfdsfds-vs-erer">
```

I use this `$regex_pattern = "/^[^.]+((\.[^.\/]{1,3}\b){1,2}).*$/";`

pattern to find this type of URL. But can not get this. Please somebody help me. I need to match total tag like `"<a href="clash/football/a-vs-b">"`

Comment: Any reason you can't use `DOM` or `SimpleXML`?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions describe operations on regular languages and `html` is not a regular language! You'll be better of by using [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

You could then take a look at `getElementsByTagName` to get all the `<a href>` tags.